# How to call an async method in render method from Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I saved data to AsyncStorage. Now I want to show all data from AsyncStorage in separate screen.
Method getData is async method. It reads from AsyncStorage.
I use code like that

```js
import React from "react";

class List extends React.Component {
  state = { list: null };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const list = await getData("List");
    console.log('LIST: ' + JSON.stringify(list));
    this.setState({ list });
  }

  render() {
    const { list } = this.state;
    console.log('state: ' + JSON.stringify(list));

    if(list || list.length <= 0)
         return (<View><Text>Empty.</Text></View>);

    return (
                <View>
                    { list.map(item => (
                        <Text tabLabel={item}>{item}</Text>
                    ))}
                </View>
        );
   }
}
```

When I run that code, i get 2 console messages:
state: []
and
LIST: [{item1}, {item2}...]

It means that componentDidMount fires after render method, that is why UI is empty.

How can I change this. I need to read data from AsyncStorage and show it in UI.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidMount` as the title says is meant to run after render. To achieve what you want to do you can use `componentWillMount`.

```js
import React from 'react';

class List extends React.Component {
  state = { list: null };

  componentWillMount() {
    const loadData = async () => {
      const list = await getData('List');
      console.log('LIST: ' + JSON.stringify(list));
      this.setState({ list });
    };

    loadData();
  }

  render() {
    const { list } = this.state;
    console.log('state: ' + JSON.stringify(list));

    if (list || list.length <= 0)
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>Empty.</Text>
        </View>
      );

    return (
      <View>
        {list.map((item) => (
          <Text tabLabel={item}>{item}</Text>
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for idea, but unfortunantly it has the same effect.

Comment: Edited message, look now

Comment: You changed componentDidMount  to componentWillMount. Thank you I will try.

Comment: Yes that's what I did